# Laravel paginator display more pages

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

what i am trying to do is to get distinct values (date) of my Model and for each date the display the corresponding data. When i make pagination of the distinct dates, it works fine, but in the pagination pages i see all the results instead of the distinct. Here is my function:

```
public function showdaily($id) {

    $capacities = array();
    // DB::enableQueryLog();
    $capacity_daily = CapacityDaily::select('for_date')->where('capacity_id', '=', $id)->orderBy('for_date', 'asc')->distinct()->paginate(2);
    // dd(DB::getQueryLog());
    foreach($capacity_daily as $cap) {
        $get_capacity = CapacityDaily::where('capacity_id', '=', $id)->where('for_date', '=', $cap->for_date)->orderBy('for_date', 'asc')->distinct()->get();
        $capacities[] = array('for_date' => $cap->for_date, 'values' => $get_capacity, 'capacity' => Capacity::find($id)->first());
    }

    return view('admin.capacity.daily', compact('capacities', 'capacity_daily', 'id'));

}
```

I have totally 4 distinct dates and 96 rows in that table. As i want to display only 2 dates per page it should show me only one additional page available, but instead of that i have from 1-47.

What i make wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toSql() method will show the query it is running, but I suspect you need to group on for_date rather than use distinct

```
$capacity_daily = CapacityDaily::select('for_date')->where('capacity_id', '=', $id)->orderBy('for_date', 'asc')->groupBy('for_date')->paginate(2);
```

Comment: After this you can use {!! $capacity_daily->render() !!} to display pagination links. They are compatible with bootstrap!